# How Can I Improve on this Solution on 1-Form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

**Question**

Let $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i(x)dx^i\in\Omega^1(\mathbb{R}^m)$ be a closed 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^m$. Show that $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^mx^i\int_0^1\alpha^i(ux)du$ defines a smooth function satisfying $df=\alpha$.

**Attempt**

Since $\alpha$ is smooth (by the problem’s assumption), the integrals in the definition of $f$ involve smooth functions $\alpha^i$. Since the composition of smooth functions is smooth, and the integral of a smooth function wrt $u$ from $0$ to $1$ is also smooth, then $f$ is smooth.

Now, we want to show that $df=\alpha$. We have $df=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$.

Now, for each $j=1,…,m$, we have

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}(x^i\int_0^1\alpha^i(ux)du)$.

When $i=j$,

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}(x^j\int_0^1\alpha^j(ux)du)=\int_0^1\alpha^j(ux)du+x^j\int_0^1u\frac{\partial \alpha^j}{\partial x^j}du$.

Since $\alpha$ is closed, then $d\alpha=0$. So, the second integral vanishes.

When $i\neq j$,

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}(x^i\int_0^1\alpha^i(ux)du)=x^i\int_0^1u\frac{\partial \alpha^i}{\partial x^j}du$.

Since $\alpha$ is closed, then $d\alpha=0$. So, this integral vanishes as well.

Now, we evaluate the integral we have left this way:

$\int_0^1\alpha^i(ux)du=\alpha^i(x)-\alpha^i(0)$ (I need $\alpha^i(0)$ to vanish)

Therefore,

$df=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i=\sum_{i=1}^m(\int_0^1\alpha^j(ux)du)dx^i=\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i(x)dx^i=\alpha$.

**Note**
First, I don’t seem to have a good justification to make $\alpha^i(0)$ vanish. Second, I don’t know if there is any part of this solution I should improve. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: The integral of $\alpha^i(ux)du$ is not $\alpha^i$. $d\alpha=0$ doesn’t mean $\frac{\partial \alpha^i}{\partial x^j}$ is always 0. Try integration by parts

Comment: $d\alpha=0$ does not imply the second integral is zero. What it does imply is that $\frac{\partial \alpha^i}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial \alpha^j}{\partial x^i}$ (Try to show this).

Comment: @Eric I tried integration by part. However, I don’t seem to make those “unwanted” terms to vanish.

Comment: @BaselJ. Yes, the partial derivatives will be equal because of exactness. However, I don’t seem to know how to make these terms vanish so I have the required result?

Comment: @MrProf Try showing that for any smooth function $g(x)$ we have $g(x)=\int_0^1\frac{d}{du}\left(ug(ux)\right)du=\int_0^1g(ux)du+\sum_i\int_0^1 u x^i\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}(ux)du$

Comment: @BaselJ. I think there is a little mistake in the computation: $\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}(x^j\int_0^1\alpha^j(ux)du)=\int_0^1\alpha^j(ux)du+x^j\int_0^1\frac{\partial \alpha^j(ux)}{\partial x^j}du$. Using integration by part on the second integral, (compare $\int_a^bu(x)v^\prime dx = [u(x)v(x)]_a^b-\int_a^bu^\prime(x)v(x)dx$), we will have $x^j\alpha^j(x)$. However, the first integral stays (and the unwanted coefficient of $\alpha^j(x)$ as well). I don’t know what I am mixing up.